# Google maps link strangely behaving

Tags: google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3

I have been searching the whole day yesterday, but I cannot find any solution to my problem, so I thought to ask you.
I have been working on a project and part of it, it is generating a google maps adress. 
The problem is that eventhough I can generate the same type of link for two different adresses, Google Maps excecutes them differently.

The first link: http://maps.google.ch/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=fr&geocode=&q=Route+de+Lausanne+37+1020+Renens&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Route+de+Lausanne+37+1020+Renens&z=10&iwloc=A
It is generated as a route.
Meanwhile the second one: 
http://maps.google.ch/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=fr&geocode=&q=Place+du+Motty+1024+Ecublens&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Place+du+Motty+1024+Ecublens&z=10&iwloc=A
It is just a pitpoint (it shows only one specific place)
Any ideas why this is happening? I want, that all the links will pitpoint and not show me routes.
Thanx in advance for your help.
Peace :)

Comment: Looks like it's the word 'Route' - if you change it to Rue, you get a pinpoint.

Comment: Yeah it actually did. Thanx a lot for your input. @sideroxylon